# In .NET, how do you make a customized control that does not display on the windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

How do you make a customized control that does not display on the windows form,  like the SerialPort or the BackgroundWorker or ImageList control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inherit from [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) rather than Control.

Answer (score 4):

Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new component from the top of the toolbox onto the form.  Embellish as desired.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

[DefaultProperty("Aardvark")]
class MyFoo : Component {
    public MyFoo() { }
    public MyFoo(IContainer container) { container.Add(this); }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Aardvark { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can derive from the [System.ComponentModel.Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) class instead of from Control.